# CW arc with JavaFX arcTo() or similar function

Tags: javafx

Is there a easy way to paint an cw arc with JavaFX arcTo() or similar function?

```
    gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
    gc.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200); 
    gc.beginPath();
    gc.moveTo(20,20);

    // CCW arc
    gc.arcTo(lastPos[0], lastPos[1], newPos[0], newPos[1], Math.sqrt(offset[0]*offset[0]+offset[1]*offset[1]));

    gcGCodeVis.stroke();
    gcGCodeVis.closePath();
```

I tried with following code, but it didn't work correct:

```
    // CW arc
    gc.moveTo(newPos[0], newPos[1]);
    gc.arcTo(newPos[0]+offset[0], newPos[1]+offset[1], lastPos[0], lastPos[1], Math.sqrt(offset[0]*offset[0]+offset[1]*offset[1]));
    gc.moveTo(newPos[0], newPos[1]);
```

Comment: 1. Is gc the same as gcGCodeVis? 2. Why do you stroke the path before you close it? 3. A complete, working example would make things easier!

Comment: What do those 3 value pairs describe? Usually there are some points given, such as the center+ start and end point of the arc or 3 Points on the arc... `Math.sqrt(offset[0]*offset[0]+offset[1]*offset[1])` makes me think it's the distance of one of the points on the arc to the center, but then you start adding it to `newPos`, which doesn't make much sense....